# Passing authentication parameters to power-bi report service on a server

Tags: angular, reporting-services, powerbi

I'm having a server with `power-bi` reporting service installed and configured on it, and from my front-end that hosts the application, I've got `angular 7` with proper `power-bi` components installed.

Since the report is on the server and it needs authentication to login, i get a user and password fill-in prompt in my website whenever i tries to access this report, and after logging in, i can see the data of my report.

My question is how can i set-up that username and password to login automatically without asking the user to enter them every time.

P.S: i don't want to use `Kerberos` to solve the issue.

Comment: @Saleh_Ahmadi In fact, whenever you are trying to access the PowerBI Report Server page, the browser prompts you to enter the username and password? And you need to find a way to get rid of it? Am I right?

Comment: @VahidFarahmandian That's right. 'till now, i've tried `RTLS` and `BasicNegotiation`, set the report connection to database via saved credentials and it's setting to **impersonate** the user, but so far, no luck. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.